# Xbox Live Gold on Two Different Consoles

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

So my brother and I both have Xbox 360s. We both also, at the moment, have Xbox Live Gold accounts, each on a different console. Mine expires this month on the 27th and his expires soon as well. Is there anyway that since they are both in the same household that we could get an Xbox Live membership for us both at once without paying for two memberships? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, an account can only be signed in one one device (whether that's Xbox 360 or PC) at a time. Unless you never play on your consoles at the same time buying two memberships is your only option.

Comment: Ok, I was just curious. But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Family memberships are an option if you have another 2 people to use them. Four(4) Gold memberships for about the price of two(2). Keep in mind if you can convince your Ma or Dad, they can use their profile to watch YouTube, SBS, and Crackle...